# How use arabic letters in php range()

Tags: php, range, arabic

I wanted to use Arabic alphabetic letters as inputs of the range function:

```
foreach (range('ا', 'ی') as $letter) {
    echo $letter;
}
```

I couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: what is the problem? you can not print it out or you need all alphabetic printed out?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using range(), because that works purely with ASCII characters, but you can do something similar with this "alphabet()" function:

```
/*
 * By Darien Hager, Jan 2007... Use however you wish, but please
 * please give credit in source comments.
 *
 * Change "UTF-8" to whichever encoding you are expecting to use.
 */
function ords_to_unistr($ords, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
    // Turns an array of ordinal values into a string of unicode characters
    $str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($ords); $i++) {
        // Pack this number into a 4-byte string
        // (Or multiple one-byte strings, depending on context.)
        $v = $ords[$i];
        $str .= pack("N",$v);
    }
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str,$encoding,"UCS-4BE");
    return($str);
}

function unistr_to_ords($str, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
    // Turns a string of unicode characters into an array of ordinal values,
    // Even if some of those characters are multibyte.
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str,"UCS-4BE",$encoding);
    $ords = array();

    // Visit each unicode character
    for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($str,"UCS-4BE"); $i++) {
        // Now we have 4 bytes. Find their total
        // numeric value.
        $s2 = mb_substr($str,$i,1,"UCS-4BE");
        $val = unpack("N",$s2);
        $ords[] = $val[1];
    }
    return($ords);
}

function alphabet($firstCharacter = 'A', $lastCharacter = 'Z') {
    $firstCharacterValue = unistr_to_ords($firstCharacter)[0];
    $lastCharacterValue = unistr_to_ords($lastCharacter)[0];

    if ($firstCharacterValue < $lastCharacterValue) {
        for ($character = $firstCharacterValue; $character <= $lastCharacterValue; ++$character) {
            yield ords_to_unistr(array($character));
        };
    } else {
        for ($character = $firstCharacterValue; $character >= $lastCharacterValue; --$character) {
            yield ords_to_unistr(array($character));
        };
    }
}
```

and then use

```
foreach (alphabet('ا', 'ی') as $letter) {
    echo $letter;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CTWqo)

Answer (score 0):

Use utf-8 as a main encoding of your page, database and your server (it allows you to use any language not only Arabic! e.g. Chinese)

If you use third parties server and you can't change configuration of your server you can always force encoding in php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and if your database does not support UTF-8, you can use binary instead of text